# Chunk a large set of characters by a specified set of delimiters and a maximum chunk size

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, strings

## Problem

I need to be able to grab a subset of characters but ensure that each set doesn't exceed a specified limit and must end with a defined set of characters. For example, say I have an entire book worth of characters, I need to chunk that into a set of 300 characters but ensure that none of those chunks is split mid-sentence.

To put it into pesudo code I basically need:

```
foreach(var chunk in text.Chunk(x).ButAlsoSplitOnFirst('.', '!', '?', etc...);
```

## My solution

```csharp
public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> ChunkWithDelimeters(this string source, int maxChar, params char[] delimeters)
        {
            var sourceSpan = source.AsSpan();
            var items = new List<string>();

            var pointer = 0;
            var lazyPointer = 0;

            while (pointer <= sourceSpan.Length)
            {
                bool foundMatch = false;

                pointer = Math.Min(lazyPointer + maxChar, sourceSpan.Length);

                if (pointer == sourceSpan.Length)
                {
                    items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer).TrimStart().ToString());
                    break;
                }

                for (var j = pointer; j >= lazyPointer; j--)
                {
                    var tempChar = sourceSpan[j];

                    if (delimeters.Contains(tempChar))
                    {
                        foundMatch = true;
                        items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, j + 1 - lazyPointer).TrimStart().ToString());
                        lazyPointer = j + 1;
                    }
                }

                if (!foundMatch)
                {
                    items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer).Trim().ToString());
                    lazyPointer = pointer;
                }
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
```

### Benchmarks

| source.Length | maxChar | delimiters | Mean (μs) | Error (μs) | StdDev (μs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7320000 | 30 | '.' | 73,622.739 | 1,412.4035 | 1,252.0589 |
| 439200 | 30 | '.' | 4,122.574 | 68.6392 | 60.8468 |
| 731 | 30 | '.' | 5.125 | 0.0466 | 0.0436 |

## My question

What is the optimal solution to this problem? Is there any way I can improve the performance of my solution?

Comment: What if the sentence is longer than 300 chars?  Which rule wins?

Comment: Ensure that each set doesn't exceed a specified limit and must end with a defined set of characters unless those characters are not in the chunk?

Answer (score 1):

## Bugfix

Your code has an error. If you take a look at the next lines, you will realize, that delimiters at the end of the string are ignored.

```
            pointer = Math.Min(lazyPointer + maxChar, sourceSpan.Length);

            if (pointer == sourceSpan.Length)
            {
                items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer).TrimStart().ToString());
                break;
            }
```

Let's make some test cases

```
        // correct
        new TestCase(source: "source", maxChar: 7, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "source" }), 
        new TestCase(source: "sou,rce", maxChar: 3, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "sou,", "rce" }),
        new TestCase(source: "sou,rce", maxChar: 4, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "sou,", "rce" }),

        // failed
        new TestCase(source: "sou,rce", maxChar: 7, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "sou,", "rce" }),
        new TestCase(source: "12,3,4,,", maxChar: 2, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "12,", "3,", "4,," }),
        new TestCase(source: "12,45,78", maxChar: 8, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "12,45,", "78" })
```

Obviously, we need to get rid of `if (pointer == sourceSpan.Length)` branch, because this branch can't work.
Unfortunattely, that lead us to new problem.
In some lines you work with pointers like a pointers, but in other places you are working with them like length. No worries, [off-by-one error](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Off-by-one_error) is most typical error.

Fixed code:

```
        var sourceSpan = source.AsSpan();
        var items = new List<string>();
        var lazyPointer = 0;

        while (lazyPointer < sourceSpan.Length)
        {
            bool foundMatch = false;

            var pointer = Math.Min(lazyPointer + maxChar, sourceSpan.Length - 1);

            for (var delimiterP = pointer; delimiterP >= lazyPointer; delimiterP--)
            {
                var tempChar = sourceSpan[delimiterP];

                if (delimeters.Contains(tempChar))
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, delimiterP + 1 - lazyPointer).TrimStart().ToString());
                    lazyPointer = delimiterP + 1;
                }
            }

            if (!foundMatch)
            {
                items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer + 1).Trim().ToString());
                lazyPointer = pointer + 1;
            }
        }

        return items;
```

## Other possible bugs

Please, note that there is next test case:

```
new TestCase(source: "12,45,78", maxChar: 8, delimiters: new [] { ',' }, expected: new []{ "12,45,", "78" })
```

This test case shows that we are not splitting our string on first delimiter. Still, I'm not sure if that's not expected. So, I will not fix this bug.

## Trim

Your code has calls to `Trim()` and `TrimStart()`.
I suppose that these calls are wrong, because there are no sense to drop whitespace characters.
I strictly suggest you to remove such logic.

## Performance

1. (just as idea) If you take a look to your code, you will notice that you scan string in reverse order. But computers are good at scanning in normal order. Unfortunattely, that didn't helped, because in such case amount of checks "is delimiter" is increased significantly.
2. Your code has conversion ToSpan() and vice-versa. But you don't really need it. If you get rid of that, you will reduce costs for a little bit
3. Your code accepts array of delimiters and use Contains over it. You can add  `var delimetersSet = new HashSet<char>(delimeters);` into your function body. After that you will be able to check via `Contains` over set, which is much faster even for single-char.

| Method | AmountOfChars | MaxChar | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ChunkV2 | 731 | 30 | 6.842 us | 0.1585 us | 0.4445 us | 6.768 us | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| ChunkV3NormalOrder | 731 | 30 | 11.766 us | 0.1925 us | 0.1801 us | 11.744 us | 1.73 | 0.07 |
| ChunkV4NoSpan | 731 | 30 | 6.657 us | 0.2251 us | 0.6496 us | 6.386 us | 0.98 | 0.11 |
| ChunkV5NoSpanPlusHashSet | 731 | 30 | 3.989 us | 0.0795 us | 0.2022 us | 3.916 us | 0.59 | 0.05 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ChunkV2 | 439200 | 30 | 5,341.912 us | 106.2519 us | 191.5941 us | 5,297.506 us | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| ChunkV3NormalOrder | 439200 | 30 | 9,622.672 us | 184.7573 us | 197.6882 us | 9,574.349 us | 1.81 | 0.06 |
| ChunkV4NoSpan | 439200 | 30 | 5,364.784 us | 104.9642 us | 194.5579 us | 5,378.948 us | 1.01 | 0.05 |
| ChunkV5NoSpanPlusHashSet | 439200 | 30 | 4,386.657 us | 115.0679 us | 331.9972 us | 4,282.553 us | 0.83 | 0.08 |

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to test for delimiters here?  From reading your code I assume we want to max chunk but if inside the chunk there are delimiters we want to break that up.  If the last section fits in the entire chunk it's not checking for delimiters

```
if (pointer == sourceSpan.Length)
{
    items.Add(sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer).TrimStart().ToString());
    break;
}
```

Also you could use IndexOfAny instead of the loop at the end

**WARNING** this code not tested and just used an example

```
var slice = sourceSpan.Slice(lazyPointer, pointer - lazyPointer);
var contains = slice.IndexOfAny(delimeters);
while (contains > -1)
{
    items.Add(slice.Slice(0, contains + 1).ToString());
    slice = slice.Slice(contains + 1);
    contains = slice.IndexOfAny(delimeters);
}
```

Now some other points that I think you should split by delimiters first then chunks.  Instead of chunks then delimiters.  If I have a string of  "12345.6789.8.654321" and split by 7.   The first two coming out would be "12345" <-- looks good but then the next chunk would be "6" then chunk after that would be "789","8","6","54321"  if we split by delimiters first then chunked them it would output what I think most people would expect.

Comment: Also if want to get fancy then you can look at this blog https://www.meziantou.net/split-a-string-into-lines-without-allocation.htm